# What's best practice for including correct answers in tree tests?

Tags: user-research, ux-field, tree

Let's say I'm creating a tree test to validate my IA for a grocery shopping website. When I'm creating the tree, I'm wondering if I should include the target in the tree, or stop the tree at the next highest category. For instance:

If I want the customer to locate cucumbers. My tree might look like:

Vegetables > Green vegetables > Cucumber

Should I include cucumber in the tree, or should it stop at green vegetables?

My concern with including cucumbers is the participant might just search through until word association kicks in, while stopping it at green vegetables might make them think more critically about it.

Would appreciate your thoughts!

Comment: What do you mean with "think more critically about it"? About cucumbers?
I think you should show it to your users and let them give you feedback on your design. It is not clear to me how the visual part of the IA would look like.

Answer (score 1):

Hello @nzookie welcome to UX Stack Exchange.

I'll reply with the last thing that you'd want to hear, it depends on the context.

If it was for a documentation, I'd avoid showing the last bit of the endpoint. You'd have two repeating content sitting close to each other.

But on the other hand, if you don't have any title for your product it'd work as a header too. Also every single SEO expert I know, loves to have those breadcrumbs :)

**Personal take:** I tend to not to include 'cucumber'. It's not a category. It's a sub page. You don't see the articles on the magazine cover UNLESS it's promoted/important.